# How to get data from realtime database to react from parents to child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on **e-commerce website** in react js and use **Firebase Realtime Database as backend**. i'm trying to get datas from RTDB and want to show on react js website.

here is my RTDB structure image(1)
[image]

this is the data that i stored..(image(2))
[image]

In above image(1), i stored my Parent node value (/Pant/Formal Pant(Blue Line) -> into caac442a-66fe-ba7e(Red line)). I did this from both node (Pant and Shirt). i'm able to get that data by manually type my path but not able to get data by dynamically.

**Here is my code for read data from realtime databse.**

```
// read data
const [itemData, setItemData] = useState([]);
const readData = () => {
  onValue(ref(database, `/products/Shirt/Formal Shirt`), (snapshot) => {
    setItemData([]);
    const data = snapshot.val();
    if (data !== null) {
      const objectData = Object.values(data);
      console.log(objectData);
      setItemData(objectData);
    }
  });
};
```

**try to map data in this...**

```
/* -----trying to read data here----- */
{itemData.map((item) => {
  return (
    <div className="item-category-data-list">
      <div className="item-type">
        <h2>{item.category}</h2>
        <h3>view all</h3>
        <div className="item-container-list">
          <div
            className="item-data-container"
            key={item.uuID}
            onClick={() => updateData(item)}
          >
            <img className="item-photo" src={item.image1} alt=""></img>
            <div className="item-data">
              <p className="name">{item.productName}</p>
              <p className="style">{item.type}</p>
              <p className="item-price-row">
                <p className="item-discount-price">
                  ₹{item.discountPrice}
                </p>
                <p className="item-original-price">
                  ₹{item.originalPrice}
                </p>
                <p className="item-discount">({item.discount})</p>
              </p>
              <div className="rating-section">
                <FontAwesomeIcon className="star-icon" icon={faStar} />
                <p className="rating">4.7</p>
                <p className="rating-people">(8.4K)</p>
              </div>
              <p className="item-id">ID: {item.uuID}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
})}
```

I want to map this data and want to read in my web site. Please give me some solution to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "getting path dynamically", but if you want to read all products - you can do that by reading from `products`, and then navigating the resulting data snapshot.

Something like this:

```
onValue(ref(database, `/products`), (snapshot) => {
  setItemData([]);
  snapshot.forEach((categorySnapshot) => {
    categorySnapshot.forEach((productSnapshot) => {
      const data = productSnapshot.val();
      if (data !== null) {
        const objectData = Object.values(data);
        console.log(objectData);
        setItemData(objectData);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

---

If you want to store all items as an array, that'd be:

```
onValue(ref(database, `/products`), (snapshot) => {
  setItemData([]);
  let items = [];
  snapshot.forEach((categorySnapshot) => {
    categorySnapshot.forEach((productSnapshot) => {
      const data = productSnapshot.val();
      if (data !== null) {
        const objectData = Object.values(data);
        items.push(objectData);
      }
    })
  })
  setItemData(items);
});
```

Comment: thank you so much @frank for your response, however, I am able to get data only for one child, but I want to get all the data that I mentioned in image(1) (indicated by a blue line)). can you please help me a bit to solve this issue? I'm almost there to solve this one.

Comment: Added a sample of that too